# HTTPhander in .NEt application, called by JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, session, httphandler

i am trying to create a pop up message that is going to warn a user when their session is about to expire (if they take too long to fill out an online form) and extend it when they click on "OK"

this is what i have so far:

```
 function ShowTimeoutWarning() {
        if(window.confirm("You will be logged out due to inactivity in 5 minutes. If you are working on something, please save your work now to prevent data loss!")) {

            extendSession();
        }
    }

    function beginSessionTimer() {
        // 3000ms = 3s
        // 300000ms = 5 minutes
        // 900000ms = 15 minutes

        window.setTimeout('ShowTimeoutWarning();', 3000)
    }



    function extendSession() {

        $.get(
            "/SessionHandler.ashx",
            null,
            function (data) {
    //start the countdown again           
                beginSessionTimer();
            },
            "json"
        );}
```

SessionHandler.ashx

```
  <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="SessionHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class SessionHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        context.Session["Heartbeat"] = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

in my web config i have the following:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="SessionHandler.ashx" validate="false" type="SessionHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

i used FireFox's httpFox to see the headers and the error i'm seeing is:

```
> <b> Description: </b>An error occurred during the processing of a
> configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
> specific error details below and modify your configuration file
> appropriately.
>             <br><br>
> 
>             <b> Parser Error Message: </b>Could not load type 'SessionHandler'.<br><br>
```

when i set a breakpoint in the httpHandler, it's never hit. so i'm assuming it never gets there.

Comment: Looks like you're missing your assembly reference (at least the base namespace) in describing the value of the "type" property of your HTTP Handler in your web config.

Comment: i don't understand, what assembly reference? there's something else i need to include in the project?

Comment: Prefix your type value with the base namespace of the project. This should be defined in your project properties under the Application tab under "Default Namespace." i.e. if the root namespace of the project—where it looks like you've let your handler reside—is called MyProject, make your type property's value "MyProject.SessionHeartbeatHttpHandler."

Comment: this is a web site , not an application :( does that mean it won't work for me?

Comment: See the answer I've provided below to inspect your project to determine the namespace of the class in the compiled assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Your class will be compiled down into an assembly with a base namespace. If you can't determine what the base namespace is, try finding the SessionHeartbeatHttpHandler class in the Object Browser in Visual Studio. To display the Object Browser, navigate the menu to View => Object Browser. Alternatively, you can bring it up with the keyboard shortcut CTRL+ALT+J.

Once in the object browser, you can use the search bar at the top if necessary to locate the SessionHeartbeatHttpHandler class. Click on the class and observe the bottom right pane. It should likely say something along the lines of:

```
Public Class SessionHeartbeatHttpHandler
     Member of MyBaseNamespace.SessionHeartbeatHttpHandler
```

Copy the portion after "Member of." This contains the correct value that should be present in your web config file.

Comment: i removed all references to that httphandler from web.config and now it works :-/